# Searching for words in a string

Tags: php

What's the best way to search a string in php and find a case insensitive match?

For example:

```
$SearchString = "This is a test";
```

From this string, I want to find the word test, or TEST or Test.

Thanks!

EDIT

I should also mention that I want to search the string and if it contains any of the words in my blacklist array, stop processing it. So an exact match of "Test" is important, however, the case is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find word, and want to forbid "FU" but not "fun", you can use regularexpresions whit \b, where \b marks the starts and ends of words,
so if you search for "\bfu\b" if not going to match "fun",
if you add a "i" behind the delimiter, its search case insesitive,
if you got a list of word like "fu" "foo" "bar" your pattern can look like:
"#\b(fu|foo|bar)\b#i", or you can use a variable:

```
if(preg_match("#\b{$needle}\b#i", $haystack))
{
   return FALSE;
}
```

---

Edit, added multiword example whit char escaping as requested in comments:

```
/* load the list somewhere */
$stopWords = array( "word1", "word2" );

/* escape special characters */
foreach($stopWords as $row_nr => $current_word)
{
    $stopWords[$row_nr] = addcslashes($current_word, '[\^$.|?*+()');
}

/* create a pattern of all words (using @ insted of # as # can be used in urls) */
$pattern = "@\b(" . implode('|', $stopWords) . ")\b@";

/* execute the search */
if(!preg_match($pattern, $images))
{
    /* no stop words */
}
```

Comment: Regex is definitely the way to go if you only want exact (case-insensitive) matches (eg. "test" but not "testing").

Comment: Did a speed test, took time on 1000 searches on my server,      [preg_match] => 0.0028190612792969
    [preg_match_with_b] => 0.0035979747772217
    [stristr] => 0.0051560401916504
    [stripos] => 0.0052568912506104
    [substr_count] => 0.005748987197876
    [strpos_and_strtolower] => 0.0058009624481201
    [explode_and_count] => 0.0069141387939453
generated by this code: http://test.puggan.se/test/find_speed_test.phps

Comment: How would I handle this if some of the variables are URL's? Such as http://www.domain.com/test.jpg. And I want to scan the URL to see if it matches my blacklist word of test

Comment: the chars you need to escape is: '[\^$.|?*+()', and it can be done with addcslashes($needle, '[\^$.|?*+()');

Comment: Hi Puggan, thanks for taking the time to help. I know next to nothing about RegEx, could you please show me an example of what I need to do? Currently I have the code

Comment: $stopWords = array(
  "word1", "word2"
  );
  if(!preg_match("#\b{$stopWords}\b#i", $images)) {

Comment: Paul: added a multiword example above

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of a few things, but I tend to use one of these:

You can use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
if (stripos($searchString,'test') !== FALSE) {
  echo 'I found it!';
}
```

You can convert the string to one specific case, and search it with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos(strtolower($searchString),'test') !== FALSE) {
  echo 'I found it!';
}
```

I do both and have no preference - one may be more efficient than the other (I suspect the first is better) but I don't actually know.

As a couple of more horrible examples, you could:

- Use a regex with the `i` modifier
- Do `if (count(explode('test',strtolower($searchString))) > 1)`

Comment: doing strtolower on both needle and haystack is 9% slower then using stripos, when i tested at my server

Answer (score 0):

`stripos`, I would assume. Presumably it stops searching when it finds a match, and I guess internally it converts to lower (or upper) case, so that's about as good as you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't reading the question properly. As stated in other answers, stripos or a preg_match function will do exactly what you're looking for.

I originally offered the stristr function as an answer, but you actually should NOT use this if you're just looking to find a string within another string, as it returns the rest of the string in addition to the search parameter.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Depends if you want to just match

In this case you would do:

```
$SearchString= "This is a test";
$pattern = '/[Test|TEST]/';
preg_match($pattern, $SearchString);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill for this.

Comment: Actually, I want to search the string and if it contains any of the words in my blacklist array, stop processing it.